# R Shiny $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a sample size calculator and I keep getting the error

```
 $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have tried everything but this error persists. A user enters some values and shiny reactivity picks up the values, checks which value the user wants calculated and returns the results. What could be wrong? My code is as follows:

---

### Global.R

```
#options(shiny.trace = TRUE)

#check for and/or install dependencies
need<-c("shiny","ggplot2","pwr","googleVis") # some more should auto load...
for(i in 1:length(need)){
  if(require(need[i], character.only = TRUE)==FALSE){install.packages(need[i]);library(need[i], character.only = TRUE)} else { library(need[i],character.only = TRUE)}
}

library(googleVis)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(pwr)

# load code for custom functions
source("plot.R") # for using ggplot

#data <- read.csv("dataset.csv",headers=T)

calculationTypes <-c("default","2p.test","2p2n.test",
                    "anova.test","chisq.test",  "f2.test",
                    "p.test","r.test","t.test","t2n.test")
names(calculationTypes) <- c("Select Function Type",
                             "Proportions (equal n)",
                             "Two proportions (unequal n)",
                             "Balanced one way ANOVA",
                             "Chi-square test",
                             "General linear model",
                             "Proportion (one sample)",
                             "Correlation",
                             "T-tests (one sample, 2 sample, paired)",
                             "T-test (two samples with unequal n)")
valueCalculate <-c("sampleSize","alternateSampleSize","effectSize","significanceLevel","samplePower",  "correlation")
names(valueCalculate) <- c("Sample Size","Second Sample Size","Effect Size","Significance Level","Power","Correlation")

customHeaderPanel <- function(title,windowTitle=title){
  tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$title(windowTitle),
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css",href="app.css")
    ),
    HTML("<div class='row-fluid'>"),
        HTML("<div class='span9'>"),
            HTML("<div class='row-fluid' id='header'>"),
                div(class = "span3",imageOutput("logo", height = "153px", width="272px")),
                div(class = "span6",h1(title)),
            HTML("</div>"),
        HTML("</div>"),
    HTML("</div>")
  )
}
```

---

### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    sigLevel <- NULL
    pwr <- NULL
    sample <- NULL
    altSample <- NULL
    effSize <- NULL

    observe({
        if(input$calculate == 0){ #check if this is first run
            return()   
        }
        isolate({
            # Read inputs and save values to database here
        })
    })

    #KEMRI wellcome Trust programme logo
    output$logo <- renderImage({
      filename <- 'logo.png'
      list(src = filename,
           contentType = 'image/png',
           width = 272,
           height = 153,
           alt = "KEMRI-Wellcome Trust Programme")

    }, deleteFile = FALSE)

    #Capture user input for calculating the sample size
    sampleSize <- reactive ({ as.numeric(input$sampleSize) })
    alternateSampleSize <- reactive ({ input$alternateSampleSize }) # conditional for t2n.test 
    effectSize <- reactive ({ as.numeric(input$effectSize) })
    significanceLevel <- reactive ({ as.numeric(input$significanceLevel) })
    degFreedom <- reactive ({ as.numeric(input$degFreedom) })
    numerator <- reactive ({ as.numeric(input$numerator) })
    denominator <- reactive ({ as.numeric(input$denominator) })
    samplePower <- reactive ({ as.numeric(input$samplePower) })
    groupCount <- reactive ({ if(is.na(input$groupCount))
                                 NULL
                              else
                                as.numeric(input$groupCount) 
                            }) #conditional for annova
    ttestType <- reactive ({ input$ttestType })
    correlation <- reactive ({ as.numeric(input$correlation) }) #should be between 0 and 1
    valueToCalculate <- reactive ({ input$valueToCalculate })

    # Return the requested calculation
    powerAnalysisFunction <- reactive({ input$powerAnalysisFunction })

    output$calculatedSampleSize <- renderUI({

      sigLevel <- significanceLevel()
      pwr <- samplePower()
      sample <- sampleSize()
      altSample <- alternateSampleSize()
      effSize <- effectSize()
      calcVal <- valueToCalculate()
      linearRegDenom <- denominator()
      linearRegNum <- numerator()
      freedomDegrees <- degFreedom()

      if(calcVal=='sampleSize')
        sample <- NULL
      else if(calcVal =='alternateSampleSize')
        altSample <- NULL
      else if(calcVal =='effectSize')
        effSize <- NULL
      else if(calcVal =='significanceLevel')
        sigLevel <- NULL
      else if(calcVal =='samplePower')
        pwr <- NULL

      if(powerAnalysisFunction() =='2p.test'){          #two proportions (equal n)
        print(pwr.2p.test(h =effSize , n =sample , sig.level = sigLevel, power = pwr ))      
      }else if(powerAnalysisFunction() =='2p2n.test'){      #two proportions (unequal n)
        print(pwr.2p2n.test(h =effSize , n1 =sample , n2 =altSample , sig.level =sigLevel , power =pwr )) 
        }else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'anova.test'){  #balanced one way ANOVA 
          print(pwr.anova.test(k = groupCount(), n = sample, f = effSize, sig.level = sigLevel, power=pwr )) 
        }else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'chisq.test'){  #chi-square test
        print(pwr.chisq.test(w =effSize, N =sample , df =freedomDegrees , sig.level =sigLevel, power =pwr ))
        }else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'f2.test'){         #general linear model
          print(pwr.f2.test(u = linearRegNum, v = linearRegDenom, f2 =effSize , sig.level = sigLevel , power =pwr )) 
        }else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'p.test'){        #proportion (one sample)
          print(pwr.p.test(h = effSize, n =sample , sig.level =sigLevel, power = pwr ))
        }else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'r.test'){        #correlation
          print(pwr.r.test(n = sample, r = correlation(), sig.level = sigLevel, power = pwr ))
        }else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 't.test'){      #t-tests (one sample, 2 sample, paired)
          print(pwr.t.test(n = sample , d = effSize , sig.level = sigLevel , power = pwr , type = c("two.sample", "one.sample", "paired"))) 
        }else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 't2n.test'){        #t-test (two samples with unequal n)        
          print(pwr.t2n.test(n1 = sample , n2= altSample , d = effSize , sig.level = sigLevel, power = pwr ))
        }
    })

  })
```

---

### ui.R

```
# Define UI for application that plots random distributions
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  customHeaderPanel("KEMRI Wellcome Trust Programme"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("powerAnalysisFunction","Power Calculations For",
                choices = calculationTypes),
    sliderInput("sampleSize", "Sample Size:", 
                min=0, max=1000, value=20),
    sliderInput("alternateSampleSize", "Second Sample Size:", 
                min=0, max=1000, value=20),
    sliderInput("effectSize", "Effect Size:", 
                min=0, max=1, value=0.80, step = 0.05),
    sliderInput("significanceLevel", "Significance Level:", 
                min=0, max=1, value=0.05, step = 0.05),
    sliderInput("samplePower", "Power:", 
                min=0, max=1, value=0.5, step = 0.05),
    sliderInput("correlation", "Correlation:", 
                min=0, max=1, value=0.5, step = 0.05),
    sliderInput("degFreedom", "Chi-square:Degrees of freedom", 
                min=0, max=10, value=5, step = 1),
    sliderInput("numerator", "Linear Model:Numerator(Degrees of freedom):", 
                min=0, max=1, value=0.5, step = 0.05),
    sliderInput("denominator", "Linear Model:Denominator(Degrees of freedom):", 
                min=0, max=1, value=0.5, step = 0.05),
    numericInput("groupCount", "Group Count (For Annova)",2),
    selectInput("valueToCalculate","Value to calculate",
                choices = valueCalculate),
    br(),
    actionButton("calculate", "Calculate")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                tabPanel(id="sampleSize","Sample Size Calc",htmlOutput("calculatedSampleSize"))
    )
  )
))#End of UI
```

What might be the problem with this code? Which atomic vectors are being referred to? How do I rectify this error?

Comment: a) Try to make your code self-contained. source("Plot.r") will fail on other peoples computer. b) strip it down to the minimum that shows the problem, and repost. There is too much irrelevant code here.

Comment: You're (somewhere) subsetting a vector, not a data.frame. `a <- 1:3; a$a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the reactive renderUI function. The results of the calculation are of class power.htest. To solve the error, I made the following changes in the server.R

```
output$calculatedSampleSize <- renderUI({    
results <- NULL
  sigLevel <- significanceLevel()
  pwr <- samplePower()
  sample <- sampleSize()
  altSample <- alternateSampleSize()
  effSize <- effectSize()
calcVal <- valueToCalculate()
linearRegDenom <- denominator()
linearRegNum <- numerator()
  freedomDegrees <- degFreedom()

if(calcVal=='sampleSize')
  sample <- NULL
else if(calcVal =='alternateSampleSize')
  altSample <- NULL
else if(calcVal =='effectSize')
  effSize <- NULL
else if(calcVal =='significanceLevel')
  sigLevel <- NULL
else if(calcVal =='samplePower')
  pwr <- NULL

if(powerAnalysisFunction() =='2p.test'){          #two proportions (equal n)
  results <- pwr.2p.test(h =effSize , n =sample , sig.level = sigLevel, power = pwr )      
}else if(powerAnalysisFunction() =='2p2n.test'){    #two proportions (unequal n)
  results <- pwr.2p2n.test(h =effSize , n1 =sample , n2 =altSample , sig.level =sigLevel , power =pwr ) 
}else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'anova.test'){  #balanced one way ANOVA 
  results <- pwr.anova.test(k = groupCount(), n = sample, f = effSize, sig.level = sigLevel, power=pwr ) 
}else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'chisq.test'){  #chi-square test
  results <- pwr.chisq.test(w =effSize, N =sample , df =freedomDegrees , sig.level =sigLevel, power =pwr )
}else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'f2.test'){         #general linear model
  results <- pwr.f2.test(u = linearRegNum, v = linearRegDenom, f2 =effSize , sig.level = sigLevel , power =pwr ) 
}else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'p.test'){        #proportion (one sample)
  results <- pwr.p.test(h = effSize, n =sample , sig.level =sigLevel, power = pwr )
}else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 'r.test'){        #correlation
  results <- pwr.r.test(n = sample, r = correlation(), sig.level = sigLevel, power = pwr )
}else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 't.test'){      #t-tests (one sample, 2 sample, paired)
  results <- pwr.t.test(n = sample , d = effSize , sig.level = sigLevel , power = pwr , type = c("two.sample", "one.sample", "paired")) 
}else if(powerAnalysisFunction() == 't2n.test'){        #t-test (two samples with unequal n)        
  results <- pwr.t2n.test(n1 = sample , n2= altSample , d = effSize , sig.level = sigLevel, power = pwr )
}else{
  results <- " "
}    
return(tags$div(results))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This has no corresponding entry in `ui.R`

```
ttestType <- reactive ({ input$ttestType })
```

Comment: I had already tried testing that & I can confidently say corresponding entry for ttestType does not affect the error.